# How to annotate attrs field with validator?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, newtype, python-attrs

I am having trouble annotating attrs class attribute.

I am using NewType for defining new UserId type and attrs frozen classes.

This is code where mypy doesn't complain and everything is alright:

```
from typing import NewType
from attr import frozen, field


UserId = NewType("UserId", str)


@frozen
class Order:
    id: UserId = field()
```

mypy does not have any issues when checking this code.
The problem appears after using validators from attrs.

```
from typing import NewType
from attr import frozen, field, validators


UserId = NewType("UserId", str)


@frozen
class Order:
    id: UserId = field(validator=validators.matches_re("^\d+$"))
```

mypy now complains about incorrect types:

> project/test_annotation.py:10: error: Incompatible types in assignment
> (expression has type "str", variable has type "UserId")  [assignment]
>
> Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

I don't understand how field() returns string type right now.

Can somebody explain that? Also, how can we work around this problem?

env:

> Python 3.10.6
>
> attrs==22.1.0
>
> cattrs==22.2.0

Answer (score 1):

To make it happy, `cast`. `field` is considerably complicated, your `field` returns a `str` thanks to [this overload](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/main/src/attr/__init__.pyi#L265):

```
... # other overloads
# This form catches an explicit None or no default and infers the type from the
# other arguments.
@overload
def field(
    *,
    default: None = ...,
    validator: Optional[_ValidatorArgType[_T]] = ...,
    repr: _ReprArgType = ...,
    hash: Optional[bool] = ...,
    init: bool = ...,
    metadata: Optional[Mapping[Any, Any]] = ...,
    converter: Optional[_ConverterType] = ...,
    factory: Optional[Callable[[], _T]] = ...,
    kw_only: bool = ...,
    eq: Optional[_EqOrderType] = ...,
    order: Optional[_EqOrderType] = ...,
    on_setattr: Optional[_OnSetAttrArgType] = ...,
    alias: Optional[str] = ...,
) -> _T: ...
```

It basically says "when `validators` is a [sequence of or one of] validators working on some type `T`, then `field` returns `T`".

So, you pass a validator that works on `str`, and thus `field` type is `str` as well. `NewType("UserID", str)` is **not** a subtype of `str`, so this assignment fails. You have two major options:

- cast to desired type:

  ```py
  from typing import cast

  ...
  @frozen
  class Order:
       id: UserId = cast(str, field(validator=validators.matches_re("^\d+$")))
  ```
- create your own validator. You don't need to replicate the logic, only change the signature and call original implementation with `type: ignore` or casts.

  ```py
  from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Callable, Match, Optional, Pattern, Union, cast
  if TYPE_CHECKING:
       from attr import _ValidatorType

  def userid_matches_re(
       regex: Union[Pattern[str], str],
       flags: int = ...,
       func: Optional[
           Callable[[str, str, int], Optional[Match[str]]]
       ] = ...,
  ) -> '_ValidatorType[UserID]':
       return cast('_ValidatorType[UserID]', validators.matches_re(regex, flags, func))
  ```

  ... and use it in your class instead of `validators.matches_re`. The signature above is stolen from [stubs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/main/src/attr/validators.pyi#L58) with `AnyStr` replaced with `str`, because you don't allow `bytes` anyway.

I'd recommend the first variant, because another solution is just more boilerplate with the same `cast` as a result, it gives you no more safety. However, it may be viable if you have many fields with this validator.